# Ruby on Rails: running Typhoeus on Windows 7 (64 bit)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, typhoeus

I can't get Typhoeus gem to work on my Windows 7 machine.

Basically, it doesn't find "native.so" file in "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/typhoeus-0.2.4/ext/typhoeus/". How do I fix this?

```
 C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/typhoeus-0.2.4/lib/typhoeus.rb:10:in
 `require': 126: The specified module
 could not be found.   -
 C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/typhoeus-0.2.4/ext/typhoeus/native.so
 (LoadError)    from
 C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/typhoeus-0.2.4/lib/typhoeus.rb:10:in
 `<top (required)>'     from
 C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in
 `require'  from
 C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in
 `block (2 levels) in require'  from
 C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in
 `each'     from
 C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in
 `block in require'     from
 C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in
 `each'     from
 C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in
 `require'  from
 C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.13/lib/bundler.rb:120:in`require'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems that typhoeus requires curl as development library to successfully compile it's `native.so` extension.

First you need to install [RubyInstaller DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) from [downloads page](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads).
Second you will need to get curl and development headers and libraries for MinGW, which you can find instructions on our mailing list:

http://groups.google.com/group/rubyinstaller/browse_thread/thread/c8a4bdb6663cbf7c

To the record, that same post mentions how unsuccessfully was the user attempt to get the gem to work on Windows and he ended switching to curb.

PS: while others might say that *.so is UNIX/POSIX convention for shared objects, is the extension Ruby decided to use for Windows C-Extensions, like Python uses `*.pyd` for their extensions.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me (Win7 x64) was to download the .dll from the link called `Download libcurl.dll (all versions) only`, found here: http://www.paehl.com/open_source/?CURL_7.35.0.

After extracting I took the .dll file from the `NoSSL/SSL` directory (either seems to work, I used `SSL` just to be sure). I copied the file into Ruby's /bin directory and Typhoeus worked.

Note: You can't use the x64 version of the .dll because Ruby is 32-bit. Typhoeus didn't react to the x64 file.

Hopefully this will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

if that gem is looking for `native.so` then it might not work with windows, `*.so` is the *NIX  equivalent of `*.dll` for windows a "shared object " or " dynamically linked library"  file. So it might really  need `native.dll`, or be a gem built on platform dependent code. Look at their documentation, this is just a shot in the dark.

then again, it says something happened in native.so ( LoadError) so maybe its begin executed, idk